# The motivation for wedge product

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, differential-geometry, tensors, exterior-algebra

For $v_1=ae_1+be_2$ and $v_2=ce_1+de_2$.Then in the form of wedge product

$$v_1\wedge v_2=(ad-bc)e_1\wedge e_2$$

But we also have its formula in the dual form.If we set $f\in A_k (V)$ ,and $g\in A_l (V)$.Then we have the formula:
$$f\wedge g(v_1,v_2,...,v_{k+l})=\sum_{\sigma\in(k,l)-shuffles}(sgn\sigma)f(v_{\sigma (1)},...,v_{\sigma (k)})g(v_{\sigma (k)},...,v_{\sigma (k+l)}) \tag1$$

More specially for two covectors:
$$f\wedge g(v_1,v_2)=f(v_1)g(v_2)-f(v_2)g(v_1)$$

Then we set $f(v_1)=a,f(v_2)=c,g(v_1)=b,g(v_2)=d$,then the result is $ad-bc$,which corresponds with the coefficients of the wedge product for vectors.

Here is my confusion:

$(Q_1)$. Is it just a coincidence? Or can we say the coincidence motivates us to define a formula like $(1)$ in the dual form?

$(Q_2)$. Does it happen in a higher dimension vector space with more vectors?That is to say,can we use formula $(1)$ to calcutae the coefficients with more vectors in a higher dimension vector space?See wiki'spage (Content 1.2):https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exterior_algebra

$(Q_3)$. Can we generalize $(1)$ in a way of fixed tensor?

For $(Q_3)$,I guess it's not because we can't have a permutation or shuffles in a fixed way.

Hope I've made my exposition clear.I'm grateful to your answer,thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems what you are missing is the fact that (for finite-dimensional spaces) there is a natural isomorphism
$$\Lambda^k(V^*)\simeq \left( \Lambda^k V\right)^*$$
where your $A_k(V)$ naturally identifies with $\left( \Lambda^k V\right)^*$.

This isomorphism is given by:
$$\phi_1\wedge \dots\wedge \phi_k\mapsto \left(v_1\wedge\dots\wedge v_k\mapsto \det(\phi_i(v_j))\right).$$

So the wedge product for alternating form is actually a wedge product of vectors, but in the dual space, and the "coincidence" is not actually a coincidence.

Specifically, given your $f,g\in V^*$, we have the usual wedge product in the exterior algebra $f\wedge g\in \Lambda^2(V^*)$, and using the isomorphism above we can see it as an element of $A_2(V)$ sending $(v_1,v_2)$ to 
$$ \begin{vmatrix} f(v_1) & f(v_2) \\ g(v_1) & g(v_2) \end{vmatrix} = ad-bc.$$

Comment: That's what I've missed!Thanks's for your answer.